# SQL Server : there are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I using SQL Server 2008, and when I try create a new table, in existing DB, this error appears:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'parceria_conta_corrente_ao' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'R_795'.

This table exists:

[image]

And I try create a new table with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE parceria_item_resgate_rateio_aux
( 
    id_parceria_item_resgate_rateio_aux int  NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    dt_conta_corrente    DATETIME  NOT NULL ,
    id_periodo           BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
    id_ao                bigint  NOT NULL ,
    id_gr_cliente        int  NOT NULL ,
    id_cliente           BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
    data_importacao_cli_gr_cli DATETIME  NOT NULL ,
    hp2                  varchar(50)  NOT NULL ,
    hp2_filho            varchar(50)  NOT NULL ,
    valor_nc             decimal(18,2)  NULL ,
    datetime_inclusion   datetime  NOT NULL ,
    status               int  NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT XPKparceria_item_resgate_ PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
        (id_parceria_item_resgate_rateio_aux ASC, 
        dt_conta_corrente ASC, 
        id_periodo ASC, 
        id_ao ASC, 
        id_gr_cliente ASC, 
        id_cliente ASC, 
        data_importacao_cli_gr_cli ASC, 
        hp2 ASC),
    CONSTRAINT R_795 FOREIGN KEY(dt_conta_corrente, id_periodo, id_ao, id_gr_cliente, id_cliente, data_importacao_cli_gr_cli, hp2) 
        REFERENCES parceria_conta_corrente_ao(dt_conta_corrente, id_periodo, id_ao, id_gr_cliente, id_cliente, data_importacao_cli_gr_cli, hp2)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
go
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: It's not an obvious mistake given what you've posted. Is there some reason why you haven't bothered with 3NF? A surrogate key in parceria_conta_corrente_ao would have been a big help...

Comment: you are trying to create a PK consisting colums that are used in the FK, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a unique index on the referenced table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_parceria_conta_corrente_ao 
ON parceria_conta_corrente_ao
(
     dt_conta_corrente,
     id_periodo, 
     id_ao, 
     id_gr_cliente, 
     id_cliente, 
     data_importacao_cli_gr_cli, 
     hp2
)
```

EDIT:
I guess the columns are not in the same order, columns in primary key must be in the same order than the columns in the foreing key.

If you execute the following:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    C1 int NOT NULL,
    C2 int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2)

)

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    C1 int NOT NULL,
    C2 int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (C2, C1) REFERENCES T(C2, C1)
)
```

You get the following error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 9 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'T' that match the referencing column
>   list in the foreign key 'FK1'. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 9
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Well, according to the screenshot, those columns are the primary key of the table

Comment: @Lamark, thanks I missed that. I edited my answer, please see it. Ironically, if the OP created the unique index I sugested it would work.